# delete duplicated xml tags

Tags: xml, ksh

Every month I get a lot of xmls.
All xml are contain document dataz.
Each document data are 22 rows, for example:

```
   <DocumentData>
      <Header>
        <Serial>74</Serial>
        <!-- 01101010111110100: John Snow - 371521 - The North - Winterfell -->
        <HeaderName>John Snow</HeaderName>
        <HeaderDelivery1></HeaderDelivery1>
        <HeaderDelivery2></HeaderDelivery2>
        <HeaderAddress>Winterfell</HeaderAddress>
        <HeaderCity>The North</HeaderCity>
        <HeaderZIP>371521</HeaderZIP>
        <MediaType>Bill</MediaType>
        <MediaColor>White</MediaColor>
      </Header>
      <Letter>
        <LetterDate>2015.10.21.</LetterDate>
        <LetterCity>Westeros</LetterCity>
        <CardNumber>01101010111110100</CardNumber>
        <TelNumber>(301)68947885417</TelNumber>
        <Lettertype>BUSSINNESS</Lettertype>
        <LoyaltyLevel>CC</LoyaltyLevel>
      </Letter>
    </DocumentData>
```

Unfortunatelly, almost all xml contain duplicated datas.
Nobody can know, which tag will be duplicate therefore one row (the "commented" row) contain good datas.

So:
Here is a part's one of my xml: (the importants are bolded)

```
       <DocumentData>
...
            <Serial>74</Serial>
            <!-- 01101010111110100: John Snow - 371521 - The North - Winterfell -->
            <HeaderName>John Snow</HeaderName>
            <HeaderDelivery1></HeaderDelivery1>
            <HeaderDelivery2></HeaderDelivery2>
            <HeaderAddress>Winterfell</HeaderAddress>
            <HeaderCity>The North</HeaderCity>
            <HeaderZIP>371521</HeaderZIP>
            <MediaType>Bill</MediaType>
            <MediaColor>White</MediaColor>
          </Header>
...
       </DocumentData>
       <DocumentData>
...
            <Serial>75</Serial>
            <!-- 01101010111110100: John Snow - 371521 - The North - Winterfell -->
            <HeaderName>John Snow</HeaderName>
            <HeaderDelivery1></HeaderDelivery1>
            <HeaderDelivery2></HeaderDelivery2>
            <HeaderAddress>Bitterbridge</HeaderAddress>
            <HeaderCity>The North</HeaderCity>
            <HeaderZIP>371521</HeaderZIP>
            <MediaType>Bill</MediaType>
            <MediaColor>White</MediaColor>
          </Header>
...
        </DocumentData>
```

As you can see, the first block (Serial: 74) is good, 'cause the commented row shows this datas...

```
<!-- 01101010111110100: John Snow - 371521 - The North - Winterfell -->
```

...and the tags are contain same datas.
But the next block (Serial: 75) is wrong 'cause one tag contains false data:

```
<HeaderAddress>Bitterbridge</HeaderAddress>
```

I have approx. 30-40 errors in every xml and I have app. 70-80 xmls in every month, so I would like to invent something, what can delete these wrong blocks.
I guess I should compare the datas of commented rows with xml tags but I don't know, how.
If you can help I appreciate it.

Comment: I guess this is when you go learn XML, try to solve your problem, and come back here when you have a specific question.

Comment: Can all mismatches with the commentline be deleted? In that case you could use `awk`: print all lines of one `<DocumentData>` block in an array, check the comment line and then print or ignore the block.

Comment: Thanks for nothing, Mr. Jackman.

Walter... thanks, I'll try it.